# WebResponse stream to WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, html, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a C# WebResponse stream that looks like this:

```
<script language=JavaScript> 
document.write('<head>');
document.write('<title> Testing </title>');
document.write('</head>');
</script>
```

I would like to put it into a WebBrowser control, how do I do that? 
WebBrowser1.DocumentStream = stream; Does nothing...

What I am doing:

```
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
WebBrowser WebBrowserResponse = new WebBrowser();
WebBrowserResponse.DocumentStream = stream;
Console.WriteLine(WebBrowserResponse.DocumentText);
```

This isnt working.

The answer is ( i cant answer my own question yet) thanks everybody:

```
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
WebBrowserResponse.Navigate("about:blank");
WebBrowserResponse.Document.OpenNew(false);
WebBrowserResponse.Document.Write(s);
WebBrowserResponse.Refresh();
WebBrowserResponse.DocumentCompleted += (sndr, ex) =>
{
Console.WriteLine(WebBrowserResponse.DocumentText);
};
```

Comment: Show us what you are doing and we may be able to help.

Comment: This code is fine. It displays nothing in display?

Comment: It displays "<HTML></HTML>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get the content as soon as you assign the stream to the browser. You should wait for the `DocumentCompleted` event.

Try this:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += (sndr, e) =>
{
     Console.WriteLine(webBrowser1.DocumentText);
};
```

BTW: You assign the stream to `WebBrowser1`, but read from `WebBrowserResponse`

Comment: The Webbrowser1 was a mistype here hehe, but anyways I tried your suggestion and now It displays: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

Answer (score -1):

Yay I got it!

```
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
WebBrowserResponse.Navigate("about:blank");
WebBrowserResponse.Document.OpenNew(false);
WebBrowserResponse.Document.Write(s);
WebBrowserResponse.Refresh();
WebBrowserResponse.DocumentCompleted += (sndr, ex) =>
{
Console.WriteLine(WebBrowserResponse.DocumentText);
};
```

Thanks everybody!